# How to increase size of text editors inside Google-Cloud-Shell?

Tags: google-app-engine, ssh, google-cloud-platform

I first open [Google-Cloud-Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/) from clicking console image on top right.

[image]

```
Welcome to Cloud Shell! Type "help" to get started.
Your Cloud Platform project in this session is set to citric-yen-197207.
Use “gcloud config set project” to change to a different project.
user_name@cloudshell:~ (citric-yen-197207)$ emacs -nw helloWorld.txt
user_name@cloudshell:~ (citric-yen-197207)$
```

---

At `cloudshell`, when I open `emacs` or other text editors whole screen is filled.

Later, I am connecting into my `google-instance` with following command: `gcloud compute connect-to-serial-port 'INSTANCE_NAME'`. After connection is completed (`user_name@instance-3:~$`), when I try to opened `emacs`, `vi` or `nano` or any other text editor their size is around 80x32, which is pretty small. I am not sure what causes this problem.

Example view could be seen as follows:

[image]

And console location is messed up as well. I am writing in one point but the character show up some other point. So text editor environment does not allow me to any adding text, after a while all characters merge together, previous lines pop up at the courser point I am writing text.

**[Q]** Is there any way to increase the width and height of the any text editors in `Google-Cloud-Shell` on a web-browser?

Comment: I cannot repro, in my case the whole screen is filled. Looks like it could be something from your environment (mine are still the default ones)...

Comment: Please see my updated question. I have not change my environment but I guess something is wrong related to the instance's default environment. Is there any way to fix it? or what may be the cause for it ? @DanCornilescu

Comment: I use to see this on old systems where the terminal came with such default size. Check with `stty size`. I used `stty rows <N> cols <M>` to adjust (but matching it with the max size may be tedious). These days they're auto-set - which is probably the case on the cloud shell itself, but apparently not on the ssh connection to your instance. Also try to adjust the window size - maybe the updated size gets automatically propagated.

Comment: I clicked to tool figure on left top; it says `Tmux setting` and check boxed following: `Enable tmux integration. Changes will take effect on the next connection.` but it did not help. //`stty rows <N> cols <M>` fixed it, but adjusting the window size did not help also. Please note that I was not able to figure out how to do auto-set so I manually adjusted the size like to suggested. @DanCornilescu

Comment: I was able to reproduce this. Google Cloud Platform has a support group that has the tools to help you. I would recommend [opening a case](https://cloud.google.com/support/) so that they can become aware of this issue and provide a response. This is not an issue that can be fixed on this forum, but an issue on the GCP side that should be reported on the above link.

Comment: @MikePerezOntiveros I opened a case but they did not show any proper help. They told me to press `Cntrl --` to fix it which is not a proper solution.